# Realized covariance estimator

Tags: julia, rcov

I want to estimate the covariance matrix using high-frequency data in Julia. I wish to start with using the realized covariance estimator. Thus, is there any available Julia code to estimate using rcov?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a package for this. Realized covariance is a very simple estimator. Let `pmat` denote a matrix of high-frequency prices, where columns correspond to assets, and rows correspond to the time-index. The high frequency returns can be obtained via:

```
rmat = log.(pmat[2:end,:] ./ pmat[1:end-1,:])
```

Note, you could speed up this computation by using a loop instead to avoid temporary allocations. Or as Oscar points out in the comments:

```
rmat = @views log.(pmat[2:end,:] ./ pmat[1:end-1,:])
```

will also reduce temporaries while preserving the neat one-liner.

Given `rmat`, the realized covariance estimator spanning the first to last time index is just:

```
realizedcov = rmat' * rmat
```

Comment: `@views log.(pmat[2:end,:] ./ pmat[1:end-1,:])` will have 2 less copies.

Comment: @OscarSmith I've adjusted the answer thanks.